# Web POS cancel results in undefined URL

Tags: square, square-connect

I have build a web application which runs in the browser on an Android device. The URL to launch the square POS app is as follows:

*intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI="+callbackUrl+";S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID="+clientId+";S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=AUD;S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD;S.com.squareup.pos.NOTE="+orderId+";S.com.squareup.pos.REQUEST_METADATA="+orderId+";l.com.squareup.pos.AUTO_RETURN_TIMEOUT_MS=3200;end*

The square POS app launches as expected. I can process a payment through the POS app and upon a successful transaction it switches to the browser and loads the callback url. This is all working well.

However, if I click on the link above to open the square POS app and then hit the cancel [x] button in the square POS app it bumps back to the browser and then reloads the URL with an undefined parameter.

E.g. the original URL is https://localhost:1337/admin/#/order/pay/f2kw0oFYNG

Then I launch the square POS app via the intent url. When if I hit cancel in the square POS app, when it switches to the browser it loads:
https://localhost:1337/admin/#/order/pay/undefined

Comment: What is the response that you're getting back on your callback URL from Square when the transaction is cancelled?  You should be getting something like `com.squareup.pos.ERROR_CODE=TRANSACTION_CANCELED`. The parameters of the URI can be parsed to determine whether the associated transaction succeeded or failed along with its accompanying metadata.

Comment: If I cancel the transaction in the square POS app the callback url is never called, it simply switches back to the browser and the previous page reloads (previous page url is not the same as the callback url) but with the undefined parameter on the end.

Comment: The callback URL should [_always_](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/web-api-android#processinginpointofsale) be called at the end of the transaction.   I'm inclined to believe that you might be running into issues due to having a url fragment at the end of your URL. In my own testing, when either processing the transaction or canceling, there parameters in the URL query returned back indicating there was an error.

Comment: A cancelled transaction would return something like "YOUR_URL/`YOUR_PATH_HERE`?com.squareup.pos.ERROR_CODE=com.squareup.pos.ERROR_TRANSACTION_CANCELED&com.squareup.pos.ERROR_DESCRIPTION=The%20transaction%20was%20canceled"

Comment: Turns out it was a caching issue in the browser. It was caching an old callback URL.

Answer (score 0):

Although you answered it yourself in the comments, it looks like the issues was the result of having a cached version of your link being used.

Just for clarity for anyone coming across this:

> The callback URL should always be called at the end of the transaction.

For example: A cancelled transaction would return `http://URL/PATH?com.squareup.pos.ERROR_CODE=com.squareup.pos.ERROR_TRANSACTION_CANCELED&com.squareup.pos.ERROR_DESCRIPTION=The%20transaction%20was%20canceled` if the merchant had cancelled the transaction.